# Anchor to overflow auto (scrollable) content

Tags: javascript

I am building a comment system, I want the user to be able to be redirected directly to the comment (just like stack overflow comment notification) from anywhere else.

Here's what I got so far. (the demo below doesn't display well, please refer to [codepen](https://codepen.io/MessizQin/pen/BaLogve))

```js
const comment_box = document.getElementById('comment-box');

const fourth = document.getElementById('btn4');
const seventh = document.getElementById('btn7');
const tenth = document.getElementById('btn10');

function comment_jump(id){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    // getBoundingClientRect: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
    // top (of this comment refer to parent) = top (of this comment refer to page) - top (of container refer to page)
    var tp = el.getBoundingClientRect().top - comment_box.offsetTop;
    comment_box.scrollTo(0, tp);
}

fourth.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    comment_jump('comment4');
});

seventh.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    comment_jump('comment7');
});

tenth.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    comment_jump('comment10');
});
```

```css
body{
    background: lightgrey;
}

#comment-box{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: auto;
}

.comment{
    width: 100%;
    height: 33.3%;
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;    
}

button{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 2em;
}

button:hover{
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="comment-box">
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>

    <div id="comment4" class="comment">4th</div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>

    <div id="comment7" class="comment">7th</div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>

    <div id="comment10" class="comment">10th</div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="btn4">4th</button>
<button type="button" id="btn7">7th</button>
<button type="button" id="btn10">10th</button>
```

The expected output is that when I click `4th`, `7th`, `10th`, it jump to corresponding area.

I will be so glad if someone suggest which part I went wrong.

Comment: you should use `<a>` instead of `<button>` with `href` attribute equal to id of the element you need to scroll:
<a href="#comment10">10th</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might I suggest trying out `scrollIntoView` as a possible solution?

```js
function comment_jump(id){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

From Mozilla's docs:

**scrollIntoView()** *method scrolls the element's parent container such that the element on which scrollIntoView() is called is visible to the user*

So it will scroll the comment container for you to the desired element.